# Can Spring Cloud Gateway provide the TIP value per route?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Is there a way for the spring cloud gateway to provide Transactions in Progress(TIP) Counts on a per route basis?

I am looking to throttle the requests based on the TIP value instead of the TPS value.

Comment: No it can not out of the box. You could certainly write a custom rate limiter

Comment: Sure, thanks!!! that is my option B.